# Socket.io, emit an event, not when a user connects

Tags: node.js, socket.io

All the examples of emmiting an event have this format:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('myEvent', { hello: 'world' });
});
```

I want to emit an event when a long running procedure ends and send it to the client. Obviously, the client is already connected.

So how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to add your sockets to rooms with `socket.join('some room')`.  The room ID (`'some room'` in the example) might be a user ID or something else depending on your needs.

When you need to emit an event, emit it to the room rather than to a specific socket with `io.to('some room').emit('some event')`. Socket.IO will remember what sockets were added to the room and emit the event to these sockets.

You can read about socket.io rooms [in the docs](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#Rooms).

Comment: So any client will get a new room. What about the name of the room? Each one has to be specific, hwo do i name them? Users do not login to the application.

Comment: Maybe you assign some ID to each run of your long-running procedure? If so, you can use these IDs as room IDs.