# Node.js hosting providers that dont throw timeout error

Tags: node.js, heroku, timeout

I uploaded my app to Heroku.

Because it takes a lot of time in one function, the response is not sent for some number of minutes.

Meanwhile, Heroku throws a timeout error (H12 error) after 30 seconds of not sending a response.

I try to solve this problem but it keeps getting increasingly complex, with socket.io and whatnot.

Are there providers that wont throw this error and will let the client wait indefinitely?

Comment: Here's what Heroku says about it: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout.  You are stuck with the 30 seconds unless you write a single byte to the response to keep it alive.  Asking for other providers would be off-topic for stack overflow as it's not a programming issue and it's asking for recommendations on a 3rd party service - both of which make it off-topic here.

Comment: This is presumably related to your other question where you also aren't including enough code context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52346849/socket-io-emit-an-event-not-when-a-user-connects

Comment: actually i tried setting some headers, to see if heroku would count it as a response but it did not work. What does writing a single byte means? The problem lies in HTTP you cannot send two responses for one request . I was responding with an html file, then sending a text file but i received CANNOT SEND HEADERS AFTER THEY ARE SENT error. So how can this writing a byte periocally work? Where do you write it?

Comment: Please avoid profanity here. I understand that you're frustrated but cursing isn't going to fix your problem.

Comment: Also, asking us to find or recommend an off-site resource, like a web host, is off-topic. What you _can_ ask about here is the code that's taking so long to send a response. If you share that with us we may be able to help you find a good solution to that problem. There aren't many situations where it's acceptable to wait 30+ seconds for a response from a server. Why does it take so long?

Comment: BEFORE you've sent the request, but after you've set any headers, you can do `res.write(" ")` to periodically write a byte to the response to keep keroku alive.  How practical that is in your specific case, I have no idea because you don't show the real context of the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Rather than find a new provider that will allow you to let a client sit for several minutes, why don't you send that work to a [background process](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing)? You can still use Heroku, it's an easier solution to implement and doesn't leave users sitting there drumming their fingers for several minutes.

Comment: @Chris Thanks chris. But the code taking so long is not an error. It's taking long because it is processing a lot of data.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks! If this becomes a solution, send me your paypal and i will buy you a beer!

Comment: @BradleyJohnson The job, when it's finished, responds a text file to the client. How can that work out with this? There is no actual file saving on the Heroku server, i just set some tags and take an array from the memory and serve it as text file.

Comment: @user1584421, I'm not saying you can't process a lot of data. I'm saying that _asking the browser (and user) to wait for that data, synchronously,_ is likely the wrong way to handle this. Queue the job and process it asynchronously, or load a page quickly and use WebSockets or web workers or something to push data into the browser when it's ready, long poll, heck, even use jQuery to ping the server every 30 seconds… This is also what Bradley Johnson is suggesting.

Comment: This is what i am trying to do now, with socket.io. Although i didn't know jquery was able to do that.